# Linker Command Error 2 with Overloaded Functions in Class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, linker-errors, replit

When I try to compile my code, I get this error:
[image]
Here is my code:

Main.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Rectangle one(5, 4);
  Rectangle two(15, 3);
  Rectangle three(9, 2);
  Rectangle four(6, 3);
  Rectangle five(6, 3);

  if (one < two) {
    std::cout << "Rectangle One is smaller" << std::endl;
  }
  if (two > three) {
    std::cout << "Rectangle Two is larger" << std::endl;
  }

  if (three != four) {
    std::cout << "Rectangles Three and Four are NOT the same" << std::endl;
  }
  if (four == five) {
    std::cout << "Rectangles Four and Five are the same" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"


    bool Rectangle::operator <(Rectangle rhs) {
            if ((length * width) < (rhs.length * rhs.width))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
    }
    bool Rectangle::operator >(Rectangle rhs) {
        if ((length * width) < (rhs.length * rhs.width))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
    }
    bool Rectangle::operator !=(Rectangle rhs) {
        if (length == rhs.length && width == rhs.width)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    bool Rectangle::operator ==(Rectangle rhs) {
        if (length == rhs.length && width == rhs.width)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef _RECTANGLE_H
#define _RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle {
private:
    int length;
    int width;

public:
    Rectangle() {};
    Rectangle(int l, int w);
    int get_length() const;
    int get_width() const;
    int get_area() const;

    bool operator <(Rectangle rhs);
    bool operator >(Rectangle rhs);
    bool operator !=(Rectangle rhs);
    bool operator ==(Rectangle rhs);

};



#endif
```

The code was just supposed to adjust the <, >, ==, and != operators, I can tell I'm messing up a simple syntax error but I'm really struggling to find it. Thank you and apologies as I'm sure this is a 4head answer and I'm just missing it

Comment: Where is the definition of `Rectangle::Rectangle(int l, int w);` ?  I can see the declaration in `Rectangle.h` but I can't see the definition/implementation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The `Rectangle(int l, int w);` methode you declared in `Rectangle.h` is not defined anywhere.